# Designing issue when change resolution of browser

Tags: html, css

I am working on this site http://zap3d.com and their is some issue with top menu bar
when i change the size of browser window menu background is cut off.

[image]

Please help.

I use this css for top menu :-

```
 .nav_bar {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(/content/img/top-menu-bg.gif);
    height: 30px;
    background-size: contain;
    }
.cen_div {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav_bar .nav {
list-style: none outside none;
float: right;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 0 20px;
position: relative;
}
.nav_bar .nav li {
float: left;
margin: 3px 7px;
}
```

and html :-

```
<div class="nav_bar">
    <div class="cen_div">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Account/Registration/">Sign Up</a></li>   
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i believe we would need your html code as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set  `min-width: 1040px;` on `body` and `nav_bar` to make it possible on smaller window.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to repeat the background :

```
.nav_bar {
    ....
    background: url(/content/img/top-menu-bg.gif) repeat-x ;
    ...
}
```